# How to remove Box from tagfield

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs6

I am using EXTJS 6 and using Tagfield. When I select TagField I am getting Box with close Icon. How Can I remove that box and close Icon and Place My own css. [MyFiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h89)

Comment: You don't. You would need to write your own extension of combo box.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Since I can not use multiple select from combobox  that's why I choose `tagfield`. I didn't understand extension of combo box.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to apply your changes to all tagfields in your project, you can simply override theme variables for this element ($tag-field-item-close-icon-glyph, etc.
) in you theme.
All list of available variables described in documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#vars

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ext.form.field.ComboBox instead of using Ext.form.field.Tag

```
    var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
      {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
      {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
      {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"},
      {"abbr":"BL", "name":"Blabama"},
      {"abbr":"BK", "name":"Blaska"},
      {"abbr":"BZ", "name":"Brizona"},
      {"abbr":"CL", "name":"Clabama"},
      {"abbr":"CK", "name":"Claska"},
      {"abbr":"CZ", "name":"Crizona"},
      {"abbr":"DL", "name":"Dlabama"},
      {"abbr":"DK", "name":"Dlaska"},
      {"abbr":"DZ", "name":"Drizona"}
    ]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
      fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
      store: states,
      delimiter : ",",
      multiSelect : true,
      queryMode: 'local',
      displayField: 'name',
      valueField: 'abbr',
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Comment: There are some purpose like `multiselect : true` is not in combo so we used `tagfield`